# How to consume Web API Core in ASP.NET Core MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, hosting, .net-core

I'm trying to consume my `Web API` core service which is hosted in `IIS 10` on my local machine in `MVC` app but, i'm getting 404 not found error whereas it works when I type it's URL in browser address.

Here is my controller code

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        //Construct API URI
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost");
        var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
        var response = client.GetAsync("/api/DeviceType/devgetall").Result;
        var stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DeviceType>>(stringData);
        var deviceTypes = _mapper.Map<List<DeviceTypeModel>>(data);
        var modelList = new DeviceTypeModelList {DeviceTypeModels = deviceTypes};
        return View(modelList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you also please share how you are trying to consume it?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it.

Comment: I'm trying to consume it by the code which is  attached in my question.

Comment: I mean the code that your call should hit.

Comment: In these cases, many times the problem is related to the verb (GET, POST,...) or the arguments of the request.

Comment: Did you perhaps forget the port? You can only have one site hosted on localhost:80.

Comment: So why does it work by typing the URL in browser address ?, also the verb method doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: I've just one website.

Comment: If application is hosted in full IIS then url doesn't seem correct unless application is configured as default website. In based address url application name is missing after localhost. It should be http://localhost/myapiapp .

Comment: I've already done but the same error still exists

Comment: what url works in browser? Also how you have configured route? Can you post code for web api action?

Comment: http://localhost/Msg/api/DeviceType/devgetall

Comment: Then you base address url should be http://localhost/msg

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now when I typed the full link in GetAsync method and got rid of BaseAddress property.